# My ssh config is 'PasswordAuthentication no' why MobaXterm can login?

Tags: encryption, ssh, putty, mobaxterm

My ssh config  is  'PasswordAuthentication no' why MobaXterm can login?

I want to know which technology is used by MobaXterm to login SSH by username and password?
I can confirm my '/etc/ssh/sshd_config' is

```
 PasswordAuthentication no
 PermitRootLogin no
```

I'm not use any private key in MobaXterm.

```
#To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

I try to use putty, it also can login by password.
is this function form this dialog?
[image]

```
login as: root
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Last failed login: Fri Apr 26 09:04:12 UTC 2019 from ipxxxx on ssh:notty
There was 1 failed login attempt since the last successful login.
Last login: Fri Apr 26 08:58:44 2019 from ipxxxx 
09:04:29 root@ aa:~>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` is a comment character, meaning that

```
# PasswordAuthentication no
```

actually does nothing.

Also, you can enable logging with

```
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

This will make it easier to debug what you want to do.

Comment: sorry it is my typo, there is no '#' in my ssh config. Thanks!

Comment: I confirm again, it is really PasswordAuthentication no, but MobaXterm can login....